# Unrelated result in the output?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

this is my query:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 [Service_order]
      ,[COMPANY]
      ,[PENDING_DAYS]
      ,[SERVICE_TYPE]
      ,[SERVICE_TYPE_TXT]
      ,[STATUS]
      ,[STATUS_TEXT]
      ,[REASON]
      ,[REASON_TEXT]
      ,[ASC code]
      ,[ASC name]
      ,[MODEL]
      ,[INOUTWTY]
      ,[Part_code1]
      ,[PS1]
      ,[confirmation_No1]
      ,[Part_code2]
      ,[PS2]
      ,[SO_NO2]
      ,[Part_code3]
      ,[PS3]
      ,[SO_NO3]
      ,[Part_code4]
      ,[PS4]
      ,[SO_NO4]
      ,[Part_code5]
      ,[PS5]
      ,[SO_NO5]
      ,[Engineer name]
  FROM ['NewLP']
where REASON_TEXT = 'Parts Not available (ASC)'
or  REASON_TEXT = 'Parts In Transit (Samsung)'
or REASON_TEXT = 'Parts Back Ordered (Samsung)'
  and PS1 = 'U' 
  and PS2 = 'U' or PS2 = ''
  and PS3 = 'U' or PS3 = ''
  and PS4 = 'U' or PS4 = ''
  and PS5 = 'U' or PS5 = ''
```

I don't know which part is wrong exactly but the reason_text should be those in the condition and first ps should be 'U' and the rest should be 'U' or empty, but when I run the query the result is not what it should be.
here is the results:

[image]

And when I use one of the reason_text in the condition only first two PS's show correctly, the rest(PS3,PS4,PS5) is not following the condition?

here is the result when I use one of the reason_Text, I only selected the columns that are important.
[image]

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your `PS*` and `REASON TEXT` where using `OR` conditions into brackets like this:

```
where (
      REASON_TEXT = 'Parts Not available (ASC)'
or    REASON_TEXT = 'Parts In Transit (Samsung)'
or    REASON_TEXT = 'Parts Back Ordered (Samsung)'
      )
and   PS1 = 'U' 
and   ( PS2 = 'U' or PS2 = '' )
and   ( PS3 = 'U' or PS3 = '' )
and   ( PS4 = 'U' or PS4 = '' )
and   ( PS5 = 'U' or PS5 = '' )
```

Remember that `AND` operator has precedence over `OR` and when combining these conditions, it is important to use parentheses so that the database knows in which order to evaluate each condition.

**Full query**

```
SELECT TOP 10000 [Service_order]
      ,[COMPANY]
      ,[PENDING_DAYS]
      ,[SERVICE_TYPE]
      ,[SERVICE_TYPE_TXT]
      ,[STATUS]
      ,[STATUS_TEXT]
      ,[REASON]
      ,[REASON_TEXT]
      ,[ASC code]
      ,[ASC name]
      ,[MODEL]
      ,[INOUTWTY]
      ,[Part_code1]
      ,[PS1]
      ,[confirmation_No1]
      ,[Part_code2]
      ,[PS2]
      ,[SO_NO2]
      ,[Part_code3]
      ,[PS3]
      ,[SO_NO3]
      ,[Part_code4]
      ,[PS4]
      ,[SO_NO4]
      ,[Part_code5]
      ,[PS5]
      ,[SO_NO5]
      ,[Engineer name]
  FROM ['NewLP']
  where (
        REASON_TEXT = 'Parts Not available (ASC)'
  or    REASON_TEXT = 'Parts In Transit (Samsung)'
  or    REASON_TEXT = 'Parts Back Ordered (Samsung)'
        )
  and   PS1 = 'U' 
  and   ( PS2 = 'U' or PS2 = '' )
  and   ( PS3 = 'U' or PS3 = '' )
  and   ( PS4 = 'U' or PS4 = '' )
  and   ( PS5 = 'U' or PS5 = '' )
```

Comment: Seems like no data matches your __correct__ where clause.

Answer (score 2):

execution order in where clause is not correct.To control do like below

```
where (REASON_TEXT = 'Parts Not available (ASC)'
or  REASON_TEXT = 'Parts In Transit (Samsung)'
or REASON_TEXT = 'Parts Back Ordered (Samsung)')
  and PS1 = 'U' 
  and (PS2 = 'U' or PS2 = '')
  and (PS3 = 'U' or PS3 = '')
  and (PS4 = 'U' or PS4 = '')
  and (PS5 = 'U' or PS5 = '')
```

Comment: but after I did it nothing was in the result grid!

Comment: the where clause is not true,so no result set..check if any of the reason_text has `Parts * condition`.

Comment: and also `ps1 to 5 has u or ''

Comment: I think you missed the fact that PS2-5 = '' doesnt evaluate null as true. I don't see any PS2-5 columns with empty only null.. so you should probably replace all those statements       PS2 = '' -> PS2 is null
at least according to your screenshot of your results.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding parenthesis like this:

```
  ...
  and PS1 = 'U' 
  and (PS2 = 'U' or PS2 = '')
  and (PS3 = 'U' or PS3 = '')
  and (PS4 = 'U' or PS4 = '')
  and (PS5 = 'U' or PS5 = '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use brackets. [`AND` is evaluated before `OR` in case of no brackets.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) `PS1 = 'U' and PS2 = 'U' or PS2 = '' and PS3 = 'U'` has the same meaning as `(PS1 = 'U' and PS2 = 'U') or (PS2 = '' and PS3 = 'U')` for example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` operator. So you need proper parenthesis to control the execution order.

your `Where` clause can be simplified like this

```
where REASON_TEXT in ('Parts Not available (ASC)',
                      'Parts In Transit (Samsung)',
                      'Parts Back Ordered (Samsung)')
  and PS1 = 'U' 
  and PS2 in ('U','')
  and PS3 in ('U','')
  and PS4 in ('U','')
  and PS5 in ('U','')
```

Comment: and (len(Part_code1) > 0 and confirmation_No1 = '')

Comment: @erfan - without seeing the complete query it is hard to tell. Post the complete query in question