# unrelated data showing in the result(And,OR condition)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
this is my query:
SELECT TOP 10000 [REASON_TEXT]
      ,[PS1]
      ,[PS2]
      ,[PS3]
      ,[PS4]
      ,[PS5]    
  FROM Samsung.[dbo].['NewLP']
where (
      REASON_TEXT = 'Not'
or    REASON_TEXT = 'In'
or    REASON_TEXT = 'Back'
      )
 and PS1 = 'U'
 and PS2 = 'U' or PS2 = ''
 and PS3 = 'U' or PS3 = ''
 and PS4 = 'U' or PS4 = ''
 and PS5 = 'U' or PS5 = ''
```

so the where clause should have those three values and PS1 should have the 'U' value and PS2 should have 'U' or it could be null and so as the rest of the PS's(PS3,PS4,PS5).

The result that I'm getting, the first two PS's are correct but starting the third 'and' ,which is the PS3 it's like the condition somehow Ignored?!?

here is the result:

[image]

I need to return those selected ones(red rectangle around them).
which part of the code is wrong.
I've tried every way but nothing returned the result that I need.
I tried this code for my condition as well but nothing showed.

```
 and PS1 = 'U'
 and PS2 <> 'P'
 and PS3 <> 'P'
 and PS4 <> 'P'
 and PS5 <> 'P'
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrelated result in the output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191687/unrelated-result-in-the-output) - your yesterday's question. You should follow the same logic applied there. Also, note that empty string is different than a null.

Comment: yeah, I tried the 'PS2 is null' but still no result?

Comment: And have you tried `( and PS2 = 'U' or PS2 = '' )` instead of `and PS2 = 'U' or PS2 = ''` ? ... I've talked about operator precedence in your previous question.

Comment: yes, when I did nothing showed in the result grid.

Comment: Because there are no rows matching your criteria.

Comment: all right, then what should I do to return those rows that I selected in the picture?

Comment: I've already said everything in the comments. I've transformed it into an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the `REASON_TEXT` values from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191687/unrelated-result-in-the-output) and looking at your expected result this comes to mind:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 [REASON_TEXT]
      ,[PS1]
      ,[PS2]
      ,[PS3]
      ,[PS4]
      ,[PS5]    
FROM Samsung.[dbo].['NewLP']
WHERE (
      REASON_TEXT = 'Parts Not available (ASC)'
or    REASON_TEXT = 'Parts In Transit (Samsung)'
or    REASON_TEXT = 'Parts Back Ordered (Samsung)'
      )
and   PS1 = 'U' 
and   ( PS2 = 'U' or PS2 IS NULL )
and   ( PS3 = 'U' or PS3 IS NULL )
and   ( PS4 = 'U' or PS4 IS NULL )
and   ( PS5 = 'U' or PS5 IS NULL )
```

Namely, you need to check for nulls instead of empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

Its the way that you are chaining the "and" and "or" together, and basically all that needs to be true in your statement is that PS5 = '' (OR PS5 = '').

What you need is to group the OR statements in brackets, something like this..

```
and PS1 = 'U'
and (PS2 = 'U' or PS2 = '')
and (PS3 = 'U' or PS3 = '')
and (PS4 = 'U' or PS4 = '')
and (PS5 = 'U' or PS5 = '')
```